# Convert cURL to PHP cURL with Authorization: Client-ID in header

Tags: php, curl

Hello i want to convert this  command line in php curl

```
curl -X POST https://api.imgur.com/3/upload -H "Authorization: Client-ID cdeebfbfe0d825a" -F "image=http://IP/output/1530096054.png"
```

MY PHP code

```
$URL = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($ch);
print_r($status_code);
```

Thanx  for help

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer when you actually ask a question.

Comment: im try alot to finde a answer but evry time show sem error

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /public_html/uploud_img.php on line 5
{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/upload","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":401}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'image=http://IP/output/1530096054.png');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Client-ID 46as4d6as54d6as46';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```